# How to publish custom API after changing the password in API manager in WSO2(above version 5)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, change-password

In WSO2 API Manager, I want to use an WSO2 ESB API to publish store management. I have change password in API manager in the API Manager and also changed `<password>` tag in **/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml** file.After changing password in API Manager **(localhost:9443/carbon/)**, we are unable to publish API from WSO2 API publisher **(localhost:9443/publisher/)** to WSO2 Store **(localhost:9443/store/)**.

We are facing issue mentioned below,

> **API Publisher - Error -**
>
> **{"PUBLISHED" : "Production and Sandbox:Error while obtaining API
>   information from gateway. Access Denied. Authentication failed -
>   Invalid credentials provided." ,"UNPUBLISHED":""}||warning**

Here is the api-manager.xml file,

```
<APIGateway>
    <!-- The environments to which an API will be published -->
    <Environments>
        <!-- Environments can be of different types. Allowed values are 'hybrid', 'production' and 'sandbox'.
             An API deployed on a 'production' type gateway will only support production keys
             An API deployed on a 'sandbox' type gateway will only support sandbox keys
             An API deployed on a 'hybrid' type gateway will support both production and sandbox keys. -->
        <!-- api-console element specifies whether the environment should be listed in API Console or not -->
        <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
            <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
            <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
            <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
            <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
            <!-- Admin username for the API gateway. -->
            <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
            <!-- Admin password for the API gateway.-->
            <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
            <!-- Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.-->
            <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
        </Environment>
    </Environments>
</APIGateway>
```

I am newbie to WSO2 API Manager. How to change password for Super admin in WSO2 API Manager? how can I publish API into store after password change occurs?

Here is the **wso2carbon.log** file

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-11 15:38:16,677] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager} -  Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway(APIGatewayManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway(APIProviderImpl.java:1587)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(APIProviderImpl.java:1391)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:164)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2607)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:4097)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:281)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor311.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:381)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:456)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.stub.APIGatewayAdminStub.getApi(APIGatewayAdminStub.java:4878)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:145)
    ... 90 more
```

Comment: If you change the password in `user-mgt.xml`, it should work. Is this a standalone pack?

Comment: @Bee... for your information, we are using Standalaone pack wso2am.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what the issue is. what do you mena by `it's working in apim`? what do you mean by `publishing in store`? you can only publish APIs from `publisher`.

Comment: what I meant to say, Change password is working fine in WSO2 API Manager , Publisher and Store. but not publish APIs from publisher. It will create APIs in Publisher , but we couldn`t able to publish APIs from Publisher.

Comment: Can you post `<APIGateway>` section of `api-manager.xml`?

Comment: @Bee... Here, i have modified my question with api-manager.xml file.Please review my api-manager.xml file.

Comment: It looks ok. Can you try hardcoding `<Password>` of `<APIGateway>`?

Comment: Yes we tried to hardcoding <Password> just like "admin@123" but not working for us. @Bee..

Comment: this is strange. can you post the complete error log which is printed in the console or wso2carbon.log?

Comment: @Bee..I have added `WSO2CARBON.LOG` file. Kindly review it and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Did you try hardcoding both new and old passwords?

Comment: Yeah! i tried both old password "admin" and new password "admin@123". when i change new password "admin@123", publish APIs is not working properly

Comment: @Bee do you have any idea for this? let me know your feedback.?

Comment: For some reason, the value is not picked. If you restart the server properly it should work. It's a bit hard to help you on this remotely at this point.

Comment: Once again, i tried to restart the server properly, its not working fine. Please give me any suggestion ?

Comment: If you can login with new credentials, that means the problem is with the `<Gateway>` config. Try to save in a different editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have solved this issue. Here, we have mention step for publish API after change password occurs,

1. First of all, we need to change password in **`API Manager Tool`**. In API Manager portal, go to  **`Users and Roles -> List -> Change Password`** and create your new password.
2. And then, we need to add new password **`<AdminUser>`** tag in **`repository->conf->user-mgt.xml`** file.
3. Finally, we need to kill/stop the wso2server.sh/wso2server.bat process file and re-start that file for executing API manager.

Regards,
Vivek KT.